# Passing along data from Razor Form Post to F# controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, f#, asp.net-mvc-5

How is it possible to pass along data using Razor in a F# MVC5 web application.

For instance, in the view below when the *PostEmail* form is posting how can I pass along the value of the *newEmail* input as well as some fields from *ViewData*?

And for the *DeleteEmail* form, how can I get the selected option value from the *emails* select?

My View: (Settings.cshtml)

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <h2 id="title" style="margin: 0 auto;">@ViewBag.PageTitle</h2> <br> <br>
    <div style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div style="float: left; clear: none; width: 45%;">
            <span>EMAILS</span> <br>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteEmail", "QualityScore", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <select id="emails" size="10" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%">
                    @foreach (string email in ViewBag.EmailList)
                    {
                        <option value="@email">@email</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <input type="submit" id=" email_delete" value="Delete" />
            }

            @using (Html.BeginForm("PostEmail", "QualityScore", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <input id="newEmail" />
                <input type="submit" id="email_create" value="Create" />
            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller: (QualityScoreController.fs)

```
type QualityScoreController(queries : DataQueries) =
    inherit Controller()
    new () = new QualityScoreController(DataQueries())

    member this.Settings(token) = 
        let db = DataConnection.GetDataContext()

        let user = queries.FindUserByToken(token, db)

        this.ViewData.Add("PageTitle", "Your QualityScore Report Settings")
        this.ViewData.Add("EmailList", queries.FindUsersReportEmails(user.Id, db))
        this.ViewData.Add("KeywordList", queries.FindUsersReportBrands(user.Id, db))
        this.ViewData.Add("UserID", user.Id)

        this.View()

    member this.PostEmail() =
        ... //need to use information sent from the form

    member this.DeleteEmail() =
        ... //need to use information sent from the form
```

---

MY SOLUTION

My View: (Settings.cshtml)

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <h2 id="title" style="margin: 0 auto;">@ViewBag.PageTitle</h2> <br> <br>
    <div style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div style="float: left; clear: none; width: 45%;">
            <span>EMAILS</span> <br>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteEmail", "QualityScore", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <select name="emails" size="10" style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%">
                    @foreach (string email in ViewBag.EmailList)
                    {
                        <option value="@email">@email</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <input type="submit" id=" email_delete" value="Delete" />
                <input name="userid" none value="@ViewBag.UserID" />
            }

            @using (Html.BeginForm("PostEmail", "QualityScore", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <input name="newEmail" />
                <input type="submit" id="email_create" value="Create" />
                <input name="userid" none value="@ViewBag.UserID" />
            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller: (QualityScoreController.fs)

```
type QualityScoreController(queries : DataQueries) =
    inherit Controller()
    new () = new QualityScoreController(DataQueries())

    member this.Settings(token) = 
        let db = DataConnection.GetDataContext()

        let user = queries.FindUserByToken(token, db)

        this.ViewData.Add("PageTitle", "Your QualityScore Report Settings")
        this.ViewData.Add("EmailList", queries.FindUsersReportEmails(user.Id, db))
        this.ViewData.Add("KeywordList", queries.FindUsersReportBrands(user.Id, db))
        this.ViewData.Add("UserID", user.Id)

        this.View()

    member this.PostEmail(newEmail: string,  userid : int) =
        ...

    member this.DeleteEmail(emails : string,  userid : int) =
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC will automagically bind form values to namesake parameters of your actions:

`member this.PostEmail( newEmail: string ) = ...`

Comment: That would be because you've specified `id` for your form elements instead of `name`.

Comment: Awesome thanks that cleared it up. Now what about items from the ViewBag is that even possible?

Comment: You have to add those as hidden fields on the form.